# Calculate coordinate of a 3D point from a line and angle

Tags: math, 3d

[image]

Basically, I would like to generate a random point C from a certain known line AB so that:

- AC = AB
- CAB angle = 45 degrees

From these the BC length and ABC angle can be calculated but I could not go further.

Any help or suggestion?

Comment: Do you know how to generate a random (floating point) number in a given interval? How about a random point on a unit circle?

Answer (score 0):

### Using complex numbers

For a point `P(x,y)`, denote `p = x + i y` the associated complex number.

The rotation with angle `t` and center `O(0,0)` becomes the multiplication by complex number `exp(i t) = cos(i t) + i sin(i t)`.

In the case of `t` = 45° = π/4, this gives the complex number `r = exp(i π/4) = (sqrt(2)/2)(1+i)`.

The rotation with angle `t` and center `A` can be deduced by subtracting `a` before applying the rotation centered in `0`, then adding `a` again.

If `C` is the image of `B` by the rotation of angle `t` and center `A`, then:

`c = r * (b - a) + a`

How to perform complex multiplication? Note that:

```
(x1 + i y1)(x2 + i y2) = x1 x2 + i^2 y1 y2 + i x1 y2 + i y1 x2
                       = (x1 x2 - y1 y2) + i (x1 y2 + y1 x2)
```

I let you apply the preceding formulae with `a = xa + i ya`, `b = xb + i yb`, `c = xc + i yc` and `r = xr + i yr = sqrt(2)/2 + i sqrt(2)/2` to get:

```
xc = ???
yc = ???
```

### Using matrices

Denote points by column vectors.

The rotation with angle `t` and center `O(0,0)` becomes the multiplication by matrix:

```
R = (cos(t)  -sin(t))
    (sin(t)   cos(t))
```

Again, you need to compute `C = R (B-A) + A`.

How to perform matrix multiplication?

```
(s  v) (x) = (s x + v y)
(u  w) (y)   (u x + w y)
```

We get the same formula for `C` as we did with the complex numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can we escalate your calculation into the 3rd dimension? I have thought to bring AB to Z axis, using pitch and roll to randomize C coordinate, revert ABC back to original AB position. But it seemed too complicated for me though.

Comment: Oops, somehow I didn't notice the "random" word in your question and the "3d" keyword.